# Why Helicopter compulsory need helipad to land?

Tags: helicopter

Our Country ministers helicopter didn't land because there is no helipad exist in my location, helicopter needs small place to land, then why Helicopter compulsory need helipad to land?

Comment: Anyone even attempting to answer rather than speculate would need a lot more information than that. Most likely it's a combination of insurance (safety...) rules, local regulations, national law, and ATC procedures in the area. But without knowing about all those it's impossible to know.

Comment: Maybe they needed to refuel? Just speculation - not enough information in the question to really answer this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helicopters don't *need* a helipad to land. It is simply safer landing in a helipad. I think the decision was taken in view of safety not to land because of the presence of the minister on board.

See this picture.

[image]

That said, why did they come in helicopter if there was no helipad?